# Bot framework load testing fails with a 400 error

Tags: azure, botframework

I'm trying to follow the instructions set out in the [bot framework documentation](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/19/load-testing-a-bot/) for load testing

First, i send my details to azure auth and get myself a token. I then include this token on my message to the bot service in the below way

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "id": "sdcsdcsd928323",
    "channelId": "emulator",
    "conversation": {
    "id": "5eak34ff2m25"
  },
  "serviceUrl": "https://xxx-bot-xxx.azurewebsites.net",
    "text": "I am feeling angry",
  "from": {
    "id": "default-user",
    "name": "User"
  },
    "recipient": {
    "id": "dack329f3nfb",
    "name": "Bot"
  }
}
```

While i'm getting a 202 Accepted response on the client. my backend logs show the below error:

```
Error: Failed to perform the requested operation on Azure Table. Message: The property value exceeds the maximum allowed size (64KB). If the property value is a string, it is UTF-16 encoded and the maximum number of characters should be 32K or less.
RequestId:79e296f0-3002-0039-37e5-390397000000
```

i guess the bot is trying to save its state in azure table but some value is too large. Any thoughts on where i might be going wrong?

I get a subsequent error message as well: Guessing its correlated

```
Error: Request to 'https://xxxx-xxx-xxxx.azurewebsites.net/v3/conversations/5eak34ff2m25/activities/sdcsdcsd928323' failed: [404] Not Found
```

Comment: I use **TableBotDataStore** with bot application and do load testing, get 202 response, but not get issue about Azure table storage. Could you clarify more about "my backend logs show the below error"? What do you do to get the log?

Comment: Are you using a custom state client?  Have you also implemented a MockChannel, for the bot's replies?  https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Samples/blob/master/blog-samples/CSharp/MockChannel/Controllers/MockChannelController.cs

Comment: Please share the stack trace for the errors you're seeing.

Comment: @EricDahlvang - sorry for the late response. Regarding the MockChannel , i'm afraid im not familiar with C# code so here are the steps i did

1. Deployed the bot 
2. Used a rest client to retrieve a JWT token from MS
3. Send a post message to the bot with the access token

Comment: @FeiHan - so for some reason , the bot seems to be sending a 202 response to my message but in the logs i see the above mentioned error stating that i've exceeded the property value

Answer (score 0):

This

> Error: Request to
>   'https://xxxx-xxx-xxxx.azurewebsites.net/v3/conversations/5eak34ff2m25/activities/sdcsdcsd928323'
>   failed: [404] Not Found

Is due to not having a MockChannel setup: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Samples/blob/master/blog-samples/CSharp/MockChannel/Controllers/MockChannelController.cs  This is a c# example, but shows how to properly respond to the endpoints:

```
v3/conversations/{conversationId}/attachments/UploadAttachment
v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities/{activityId}/members/GetActivityMembers
v3/conversations/{conversationId}/members/GetConversationMembers
v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities/{activityId}/DeleteActivity
v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities/{activityId}/UpdateActivity
v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities/{activityId}/ReplyToActivity
v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities/SendToConversation
v3/conversations/CreateConversation
```

This

> Error: Failed to perform the requested operation on Azure Table.
>   Message: The property value exceeds the maximum allowed size (64KB).
>   If the property value is a string, it is UTF-16 encoded and the
>   maximum number of characters should be 32K or less.
>   RequestId:79e296f0-3002-0039-37e5-390397000000

Is related to something else.  What is being stored in bot state (userdata, conversationdata, privateconversationdata, and dialogdata)?

Comment: we are storing all of those objects except dialogData

Comment: What is stored in these data bags?

Comment: right now , we're storing our user info in userdata (unique id (less than 64 kb) , multiple timestamps ) - the conversationData , we store some UUID.v4() . We also store a bunch of unique ids for multiple users which uses the shortid npm module to generate characters (7-14 chars long with human readable chars)

Comment: the maximum number of characters should be 32K or less